# How to send limited json data (stored in SPIFF) to a local server from esp8266?

Tags: json, arduino, wifimanager, arduino-esp8266

An example code:

```
#include <FS.h>                   //this needs to be first, or it all crashes and burns...

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

//needed for library
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

#include <ArduinoJson.h>          //https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

//define your default values here, if there are different values in config.json, they are overwritten.
char mqtt_server[40];
char mqtt_port[6] = "8080";
char blynk_token[34] = "YOUR_BLYNK_TOKEN";

//flag for saving data
bool shouldSaveConfig = false;

//callback notifying us of the need to save config
void saveConfigCallback () {
  Serial.println("Should save config");
  shouldSaveConfig = true;
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  //clean FS, for testing
  //SPIFFS.format();

  //read configuration from FS json
  Serial.println("mounting FS...");

  if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("mounted file system");
    if (SPIFFS.exists("/config.json")) {
      //file exists, reading and loading
      Serial.println("reading config file");
      File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");
      if (configFile) {
        Serial.println("opened config file");
        size_t size = configFile.size();
        // Allocate a buffer to store contents of the file.
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);

        configFile.readBytes(buf.get(), size);
        DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
        JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.parseObject(buf.get());
        json.printTo(Serial);
        if (json.success()) {
          Serial.println("\nparsed json");

          strcpy(mqtt_server, json["mqtt_server"]);
          strcpy(mqtt_port, json["mqtt_port"]);
          strcpy(blynk_token, json["blynk_token"]);

        } else {
          Serial.println("failed to load json config");
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("failed to mount FS");
  }
  //end read



  // The extra parameters to be configured (can be either global or just in the setup)
  // After connecting, parameter.getValue() will get you the configured value
  // id/name placeholder/prompt default length
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_server("server", "mqtt server", mqtt_server, 40);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_port("port", "mqtt port", mqtt_port, 5);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_blynk_token("blynk", "blynk token", blynk_token, 32);

  //WiFiManager
  //Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around
  WiFiManager wifiManager;

  //set config save notify callback
  wifiManager.setSaveConfigCallback(saveConfigCallback);

  //set static ip
  wifiManager.setSTAStaticIPConfig(IPAddress(10,0,1,99), IPAddress(10,0,1,1), IPAddress(255,255,255,0));

  //add all your parameters here
  wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_server);
  wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_port);
  wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_blynk_token);

  //reset settings - for testing
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();

  //set minimu quality of signal so it ignores AP's under that quality
  //defaults to 8%
  //wifiManager.setMinimumSignalQuality();

  //sets timeout until configuration portal gets turned off
  //useful to make it all retry or go to sleep
  //in seconds
  //wifiManager.setTimeout(120);

  //fetches ssid and pass and tries to connect
  //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
  //here  "AutoConnectAP"
  //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
  if (!wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP", "password")) {
    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
    delay(3000);
    //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
    ESP.reset();
    delay(5000);
  }

  //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
  Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");

  //read updated parameters
  strcpy(mqtt_server, custom_mqtt_server.getValue());
  strcpy(mqtt_port, custom_mqtt_port.getValue());
  strcpy(blynk_token, custom_blynk_token.getValue());

  //save the custom parameters to FS
  if (shouldSaveConfig) {
    Serial.println("saving config");
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    json["mqtt_server"] = mqtt_server;
    json["mqtt_port"] = mqtt_port;
    json["blynk_token"] = blynk_token;

    File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w");
    if (!configFile) {
      Serial.println("failed to open config file for writing");
    }

    json.printTo(Serial);
    json.printTo(configFile);
    configFile.close();
    //end save
  }

  Serial.println("local ip");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


}
```

I got this code from here (https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/01/08/esp8266-posting-json-data-to-a-flask-server-on-the-cloud/):

```
HTTPClient http; //Declare object of class HTTPClient
http.begin("http://anteph.pythonanywhere.com/postjson"); //Specify request destination
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //Specify content-type header

int httpCode = http.POST(JSONmessageBuffer); //Send the request
String payload = http.getString(); //Get the response payload
Serial.println(httpCode); //Print HTTP return code
Serial.println(payload); //Print request response payload
http.end(); //Close connection
```

But If I use:

```
int httpCode = http.POST(JSONmessageBuffer); //Send the request
```

This will send all the json data (i.e mqtt_server, mqtt_port, blynk_token). But I want to send only "blynk_token" and not the rest json data to server, So how can I achieve this?

Please suggest.

Comment: Where is JSONmessageBuffer declared? Can't help you if you don't show us whats inside your buffer.

Comment: @TomStein I am new and learning this, I don't have any code yet with me. But I am currently confused with the StaticJsonBuffer & DynamicJsonBuffer. Basically I want to read only "blynk_token" from SPIFF and not the rest. So If you can help me out will be really helpfull to me. Currently just want to learn how to read and write limited Json data from SPIFF using DynamicJsonBuffer. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you see the ConfigFile example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer your question regarding "how to read and write limited Json data from SPIFF using DynamicJsonBuffer" you can take a look at your code right here where you read in the data.

```
if (configFile) {
    Serial.println("opened config file");
    size_t size = configFile.size();
    // Allocate a buffer to store contents of the file.
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);

    configFile.readBytes(buf.get(), size);
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.parseObject(buf.get());
    json.printTo(Serial);
    if (json.success()) {
        Serial.println("\nparsed json");

        strcpy(mqtt_server, json["mqtt_server"]); // copy mqtt_server value
        strcpy(mqtt_port, json["mqtt_port"]);  // copy mqtt_port value
        strcpy(blynk_token, json["blynk_token"]);  // copy blynk_token value

    } else {
        Serial.println("failed to load json config");
    }
}
```

after this piece of code you have your 3 variables filled up with values. 
These are `mqtt_server`, `mqtt_port` and `blynk_token`, which now contain the values read from the json which was saved in SPIFF.

If you then want to send the `blynk_token` to your local server you will have to put only that varialbe in your `JSONmessageBuffer`.

like so:

```
StaticJsonBuffer<300> JSONbuffer;   //Declaring static JSON buffer
JsonObject& JSONencoder = JSONbuffer.createObject();

JSONencoder["blynk_token"] = blynk_token; // add blynk_token to the values sent to the server

char JSONmessageBuffer[300];
JSONencoder.prettyPrintTo(JSONmessageBuffer, sizeof(JSONmessageBuffer));
Serial.println(JSONmessageBuffer);

HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

http.begin("http://anteph.pythonanywhere.com/postjson");      //Specify request destination
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  //Specify content-type header

int httpCode = http.POST(JSONmessageBuffer);   //Send the request
String payload = http.getString();                                        //Get the response payload

Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

http.end();  //Close connection
```

this line `JSONencoder["blynk_token"] = blynk_token;` is your way to go. Here you say which values you want to sent to your server.

This [tutorial](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/01/08/esp8266-posting-json-data-to-a-flask-server-on-the-cloud/) might also help you :)

Comment: Thanks, Actually I already read that tutorial but as I said I am a learner so was confused between DynamicJsonBuffer & StaticJsonBuffer and was no sure whether I can use both of them in the same code or not. But Thanks you cleard it out. Now If I want to send two variables (i.e mqtt_server & blynk_token), what will be my code line (JSONencoder["blynk_token"] = blynk_token;)?

Comment: You add a second line. 

Like this: 
JSONencoder["mqtt_server"] = mqtt_server;